# "Good enough" random number in BSC

Tags: randomness, bsc

I'm trying to develop a weighted probability selection algorithm on BSC and I think I need an algorithm that can generate a random number within a given range for that.

What would be a "good enough" way to achieve that?
I know there's a lot of problems with RNG in smart contracts, but is there a solution that's practically safe enough for BSC?
For example if I'm not mistaken the miners all belong to Binance there, so as long you trust Binance (I know that this goes against the philosophy of crypto..) there shouldn't be mining attacks.

Comment: I am pretty sure that some validators do not belong to binance, at least since mid-february.